# Git command to list all files in working directory

Tags: git, fzf

I need a `git` command (or a bash alternative) to quickly find all the files in a working directory.

I'm trying to improve `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` for [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) which currently is `git ls-files`. The problem with that is that new files are not findable with that command. I'd also like to get rid of deleted files in the result. The command should not return any file ignored by git.

I've tried

`export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='{ git ls-files & git ls-files --other --exclude-standard; }'`

but it still show deleted files.

Comment: Why don't you just use ls?

Comment: I'd like to benefit from the .gitignore settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ git ls-files -o -c --exclude-standard > /tmp/c; git ls-files -d > /tmp/d; grep -vf /tmp/d /tmp/c
```

**Explained:**

`git ls-files -o -c --exclude-standard` - produces a list of files we want to return; saved to a temp file `/tmp/c`

`git ls-files -d` - this is the list of deleted files which are unwanted per the OP; saved to another temp file `/tmp/d`

`grep -vf /tmp/d /tmp/c` returns all lines from `/tmp/c` with the lines from `/tmp/d` removed

**Without the tmp files:**

```
grep -vf <(git ls-files -d) <(git ls-files -o -c --exclude-standard)
```

Comment: It seems to work great! I'm not a fan of creating temp files though. Do you have any idea of how to avoid it? If not, I'll accept anyway

Comment: Great answer. Saved my life. thanks a million